# Is my deduction about multiple-inheritance correct?

Tags: c++

I'm doing C++ and Java courses together. My Java instructor was like, "there is no multiple inheritance in Java for good. I wonder how the ambiguity issues are resolved in C++". And our C++ instructor was like..."so you see the ambiguity, that's why we should only use it when it's absolutely necessary"

Ambiguity obviously refers to the base classes from which the sub-class is derived having some member function or member variable with the same signature/type-cum-identifier.

He never explained how that ambiguity is resolved. So, I decided to try out on my own and began with the scope resolution operator and it seemed to work for both ambiguous functions and variables. So, I think we should be fine. Then why does multiple inheritance still get bad reps? I mean, the ambiguity can easily be resolved using the binary scope resolution operator.

Comment: Afaik, it's resolved through the scope operator `::`.

Comment: have you read this: http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond?

Comment: It's problem is that you can end up with weirdly shaped hierarchies (like diamonds), which cause their own problems.

Comment: [The dreaded diamond inheritance](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond).

Comment: Are you basically asking "why is multiple inheritance in C++ considered a bad thing?"?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: I guess.